# Как искусственно ограничить значение переменной?

Tags: c++

В программе много сложных арифметических операций присвоения значений переменным. Мне нужно ограничить значение этих самых переменных. Хотел делать через `if` но получается долго и много лишнего кода. Может кто подскажет как искусственно ограничить значение переменной?

Comment: Ну, раз уж C++, то напишите свой класс, какой-нибудь `number`, перегрузите для него все арифметические операторы и выбрасывайте исключение, если значение превысит нечто :)

А вообще не очень понятны эти ограничения. Смахивает на [индусский дебагинг](http://ato.su/01b) :)

Answer (score 2):

Не забывайте про ООП. Создайте класс для работы с переменными.

Допустим так:

```
class ShortInt
{
private:
    int value = 0;

public:
    int get()
    {
        return value;
    }

    int set(int _value)
    {
        if (...) {
            value = _value;
            return 1;
        }
        return #error;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ну и для удобства перегрузите все операторы, + - * / ++ -- += -= = и т.д.
Классов должно быть столько же сколько ваших типов данных.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите свой класс, какой-нибудь number, перегрузите для него все арифметические операторы и выбрасывайте исключение, если значение превысит нечто :) А вообще не очень понятны эти ограничения.

Answer (score 0):

Например, если вы хотите, чтобы значение переменной `A` никогда не выходило за пределы промежутка `[a;b]`, то это можно сделать так:

```
int A = a + B % (b-a+1);
```

`B` - необработаная переменная